# Pandas Reassign Row Values in Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

My input dataframe is;

```
ID   Amount   result
45   1        default
46   2        default
47   3        default
48   5        default
48   10       default
49   12       default
50   5        default
50   7        default
50   9        default
```

Desired output is;

```
ID   Amount   result
45   1        default1
46   2        default1
47   3        default1
48   5        default1
48   10       default2
49   12       default1
50   5        default1
50   7        default2
50   9        default3
```

If ID is not changed default string should increase like this "default1", "default2". First is should always be "default1".

Could you please help me about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `groupby().cumcount()`:

```
df['result'] += df.groupby('ID').cumcount().add(1).astype(str)
```

Output:

```
   ID  Amount    result
0  45       1  default1
1  46       2  default1
2  47       3  default1
3  48       5  default1
4  48      10  default2
5  49      12  default1
6  50       5  default1
7  50       7  default2
8  50       9  default3
```